# Extracting sub-streams, based on a termination attribute

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

I have a stream where the events look something like this:

```
{ 
  endOfSequence : false,
  sequenceId: 12345,
  data: [.....]
}
```

I need to terminate the sequence when `endOfSequence === true`. I started with `takeWhile`:

```
seq = stream.takeWhile( function(event){
    return !event.endOfSeq;
});
```

but the problem is that I miss the last event.

I can obviously write code that accomplishes the same thing, for example:

```
function beforeEnd(event){
    return !event.endOfSeq;
}
seq = stream.takeWhile(beforeEnd)
            .merge(stream.skipWhile(beforeEnd).take(1));
```

But this is a bit ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom handler with [Bacon.withHandler](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#observable-withhandler) that emits a `Bacon.End()` when you get the `endOfSequence`.

```
seq.withHandler(function(event) {
    var ret = this.push(event)
    if(event.hasValue() && event.value().endOfSequence) {
       ret = this.push(new Bacon.End()) 
    }
    return ret
})
```

A working example can be found in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omahlama/wfs1wwmv/).

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer adapted for for baconjs v3:

```
takeUntilLastEventSatisfies = (predicate, observable) =>
    observable.transform(
        (baconEvent, sink) => {
            if (!Bacon.hasValue(baconEvent)) {// error or end
                return sink(baconEvent);
            }
                
            if (predicate(baconEvent.value)) {
                sink(baconEvent);
                return sink(new Bacon.End());
            }
                
            return sink(baconEvent);
        })
    );
```